# How Do You Scrape (with Python) a Website That Is Not Formatted Like A Table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to scrape this website [Different Types of Beer](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/article/27/different-types-of-beers.html)  using BeautifulSoup and return each style of beer, the ABV of each, and the 'Pairs With' part. Once scraped I am looking to put all of those values into a table where I can take user input to filter it and return beer recommendations for the user based on their cuisine and ABV preference.

I have been trying many different approaches but can't figure it out at all. So far I can only get the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd
import csv

r = requests.get("https://www.webstaurantstore.com/article/27/different-types-of-beers.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
beer_titles = soup.find_all('h3')[3:-1]
beer_titles_list = []
for b in beer_titles:
    result = b.text.strip()
    beer_titles_list.append(result)
beer_titles_list
```

This correctly locates the beer titles, but I am unable to locate the ABV and "Pairs with" values.

I am not necessarily looking for the exact answer because I understand that there is a lot more work to be done. I am more just looking for any tips or ways to alter/add to my code that will guide me to my goal.

Comment: This is far too broad/vague for Stack Overflow, please see [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a look at the HTML and decide how to locate the elements you need. In the case of this website, you have found how to locate the titles using the `H3` tag. The other elements are nearby.

You could iterate through your `H3` elements and then use this to locate the adjacent `ABV` and `Pairs with` elements. These are found in `<p>` elements which also contain unwanted `<b>` tags. Once you have your `H3` element, you can then further search [sideways or up and down](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways) if needed.

BeautifulSoup also lets you locate all of the text elements by searching for `NavigableString` instances. You can then take just the second element which skips over the `<b>` tag, which removes the need for using a regular expression.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import csv

def get_text(e):
    text_elements = e.find_all(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, NavigableString))

    if len(text_elements) > 1:
        return text_elements[1].strip()
    else:
        return ''

r = requests.get("https://www.webstaurantstore.com/article/27/different-types-of-beers.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
beer_titles_list = []

for beer_title in soup.find_all('h3')[3:-1]:
    result = beer_title.text.strip()
    p = beer_title.find_all_next('p', limit=5)
    abv = get_text(p[1])
    pairs_with = get_text(p[3])

    beer_titles_list.append([result, abv, pairs_with])
    print([result, abv, pairs_with])
```

This would give you output starting:

```
['American Lager', '3.2-4.0%', 'American cuisine, spicy food']
['German Helles', '4.8-5.6%', 'German cuisine, pork, brie']
['German Pilsner', '4.6-5.3%', 'German cuisine, poultry, fish, spicy cheese']
['Czech or Bohemian Pilsner', '4.1-5.1%', 'Spicy food, Asian cuisine, sharp cheddar cheese']
```